# How to change source property of MediaElement from code behind in windows store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows store app through c#, in which i am using a mediaElement control.
There are some images in the application. I want to change the source on particular image clicks. I hv tried this-

```
 media.Source = new Uri("Assets//XyZ.mp3", UriKind.Relative); 

 <MediaElement x:Name="media" Source="Assets/Always_Up.mp3" 
               AutoPlay="True" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"  />
```

Comment: I got the solution for this. Its working fine now.

Comment: media.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/XyZ.mp3", UriKind.Absolute);